# If block not hitting when enum matches

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert a string value to number based on an enum.But even when the enum matches.The if block is never hit.This is the code

```
let item = this.gaparameterlist.find(x => x.key === globalparameter);
        if (globalparameter == enums.IASamplingGlobalParameters.PercentageTolerance || globalparameter == enums.IASamplingGlobalParameters.MarkDifferenceMethodThreshold || globalparameter == enums.IASamplingGlobalParameters.TailedThreshold, globalparameter == enums.IASamplingGlobalParameters.AvergaeDiffMethodTolerance || globalparameter == enums.IASamplingGlobalParameters.ModerationTest2Tolerance) {
            var numericvalue = +textvalue;
            numericvalue = numericvalue / 100;
            textvalue = String(numericvalue);
        }
```

This is the output from debugger
[image]

Comment: Check in your if condition there's a comma, is it intentional or a typo?

Comment: @AHMEDSAJJAD its a typo...is that the issue?

Comment: it might just be a typo. To confirm you should also show whats in the `enums` object. Maybe `globalParameter` isn't matching with any of the values in `enums`.

Comment: please share reproducable code